# pass id from select to funtion in react js

Tags: reactjs

pass id from select to funtion in react js after evry time the opions are changed i want to recive the corresponding id in updateStatus

```
                  <select>
                    {this.state.hospital.map((ele) => {
                      return <option    onChange={() => this.updateStatus(ele.id)} >{ele.name}</option>;
                    })}
                  </select>
```

```
updateStatus(id) {
console.log(id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply do

```
<select onChange={e => this.updateStatus(e.target.value)}>
    {this.state.hospital.map((ele) => 
    <option key={ele.id} value={ele.id} >{ele.name}</option>
    )}
 </select>
```